# How can i repeat my div through loop in php WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have one div so i want to repeat the same div three time when the someone open the page.
If anyone knows please help me out

Comment: This is a very basic question... what have you tried?

Comment: yes . but i am very new in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;i++): ?>
    <div>your code</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

this will repeat 10 divs for you. save as .php file

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `foreach` (but this can only be used with PHP, and not HTML directly)